# How to find asymptotic behaviour?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, orthogonal-polynomials

How do we find asymptotic behavior of Hermite polynomials? I tried to check, but i can only find the final expression but not the method.

Comment: A standard reference is Szego, *Orthogonal Polynomials*, chapter 8.

Comment: What definition do you take for Hermite polynomials? There are quite a few: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials

Answer (score 1):

You can prove by induction that the $n$th derivative of $e^{-x^2/2}$ is $e^{-x^2/2}$ multiplied by a polynomial of degree of $n$ with leading factor $(-1)^n$, hence the (probabalist's) Hermite polynomials all have leading factor $1$, and so tend to positive infinity asymptotically.

Comment: I'm taking the derivative of $e^{-x^2/2}$ since I'm using the probabilist's Hermite polynomials. If you use the physicist's Hermite polynomials, which deal with derivatives of $e^{-x^2}$, the two differ by a scaling factor, and a similar induction argument can be made.